# What is the best pattern to persist objects?

Tags: java, design-patterns, persistence, dao

I need to persist objects and I want to keep my data classes as clean as possible. The persisted classes do not feature any business-logic code, but only data with getters/setters.

I'm currently implementing a solution with the Observer pattern. Each time an Observable persisted object is modified, it fires a message to an Observer object that takes care of persistence. This way, the only constraint for the persisted object is to be "Observable". It keeps things clean.

Another solution (maybe better?) would be to implement some DAO pattern, and I'm not very aware of the way it works. Maybe it would look like `persistedObject.save();` or `persistedObject.readById(id);`. But it means I would have to define some DAO interface and then to implement the read/create/update/delete method in each and every persisted class

Comment: Please clarify the question. You can persist to a text-file, to a data-base, to an industrial-strength cloud... unless you give some more background on your needs, there is no "best persistence" in general. What do you need to do?.

Comment: For the time being, my intention is to persist objects to files using XML serialization. But in the future I may use database storage as well. That's why I need to use some CRUD loose coupling pattern allowing the implementation of different mean of storage access (file storage, db storage and so on...)

Comment: If you plan to use XML serialization i'd suggest JAXB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many, many, *many* answers to this question, data serialization or persistence is a core problem in software engineering.  Options include using databases, memory mapped files, binary and textual formats, and more.

My personal favorite for quickly persisting objects is [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), however your use case will dictate what works best for you.

You mention wanting design patterns for persisting Java objects, and while such patterns are approximately as numerous as there are libraries, here are a couple *general* suggestions:

- Use immutable objects
- Use the `transient` keyword for any fields that are not necessary to reconstruct an object
- Avoid defining sanity checks or otherwise limiting the range of acceptable values in your objects - an instance constructed from a deserialize call may not correctly trigger your checks, allowing possibly invalid objects to be constructed
- Use your serializable objects to construct more complex objects if you need more sanity checking, e.g. serialize a `StubPerson` POJO, and have a `Person` object that can be constructed from a `StubPerson` only as long as the stub's values are valid

Comment: My question was more about "what design pattern should I use to persist java objects", but anyway, the library you mention is part of the answer for me: it is exactly the kind of clean approach I'm looking for, because "Gson can work with arbitrary Java objects including pre-existing objects that you do not have source-code of." So no dedicated annotation needed, no specific inheritance from dedicated classes. Thanks.

Comment: @DariusPaulsen - I added a few suggestions to my answer, is that more what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it fits for you but since you have only bean classes you could use the [Java persistence api](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html).

Comment: I had a look at this, it is probably a clean and meaningful way of doing things, but in my case it feels like it is too complicated for the purpose. I just need some create/read/update/delete interface to access my data, regardless of the way they are stored (json and xml files, database...) I will have to write the different adapters, but I'm ok with that. Anyway, my question is more about the way to implement an appropriate design pattern to persist java objects. Thanks for having answered.

Answer (score 0):

The DAO pattern is the best one to manage data access and persistence as it has been designed  specifically for that.

Considering your needs you will probably have to couple it with some factory pattern in order to manage the different implementations (persistence adapters).

I don't know your requirements but if your application can be used by many persons at the same time you will have to care about concurrent accesses and define a policy (transaction, locking, etc... otherwise people will overwrite data each others).

Regarding your question i'd suggest [JDO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Data_Objects) (with [data nucleus](http://www.datanucleus.org/) as implementation) but the learning curve may be too expensive for your effective needs.